# Elasticsearch match all query using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

We are using Elasticsearch version 7.3.1 and Java API.

We are implementing a "free search", which means a search for a value in **ALL** the fields in each segment in Elasticsearch. If that value appears in at least one of the segment's fields, it should be returned.

Until now, we have used the following: `QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(value)` and it worked well.

As for today, we have added to the mapping file some *nested* (Elasticsearch data type) type fields.

After that change, the code above does not return the expected results anymore.

How can I implement a search in **ALL** the fields in a segment without specifying each field to search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement the logic of _all of previous elasticsearch versions (this was removed after version 6 I believe).

```
PUT stackoverflow
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "all": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "group": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "all"
      },
      "user": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "email": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "all"
          },
          "info": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "all"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically you add the `copy_to` parameter.

```
PUT stackoverflow/_doc/1
{
  "group" : "programmers",
  "user" : [
    {
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "info" :  "java developer"
    },
    {
      "email" : "demo@wikipedia.org",
      "info" :  "css guru"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can search against the `all` field

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "all": "guru"
    }
  }
}
```

*Update*

Here is an example of how to modify your query in order for it to work without `copy_to`

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "SEARCH_INPUT_HERE",
            "fields": [
              "group"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "SEARCH_INPUT_HERE",
                "fields": [
                  "user.email", "user.info"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Update 2*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String queryInput = "QUERY_INPUT_HERE";
    String[] nested = {"user", "product"};

    MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryInput, "*");

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    List<QueryBuilder> shouldQueryBuilders = boolQueryBuilder.should();

    shouldQueryBuilders.add(multiMatchQueryBuilder);
    for(String path : nested) {
        NestedQueryBuilder nestedQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(path, multiMatchQueryBuilder, ScoreMode.Avg);
        shouldQueryBuilders.add(nestedQueryBuilder);
    }

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    searchRequest.indices("MY_INDEX");

    System.out.println(searchRequest.toString());
}
```

Output

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "QUERY_INPUT_HERE",
            "fields": [
              "*^1.0"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "operator": "OR",
            "slop": 0,
            "prefix_length": 0,
            "max_expansions": 50,
            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "QUERY_INPUT_HERE",
                "fields": [
                  "*^1.0"
                ],
                "type": "best_fields",
                "operator": "OR",
                "slop": 0,
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 50,
                "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                "boost": 1.0
              }
            },
            "path": "user",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "QUERY_INPUT_HERE",
                "fields": [
                  "*^1.0"
                ],
                "type": "best_fields",
                "operator": "OR",
                "slop": 0,
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 50,
                "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                "boost": 1.0
              }
            },
            "path": "product",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This "copy_to" is copying the field to the all also? It won't use 2x of space? There is no other way to do that?

Comment: This is the easiest way without changing your search every time you add a field. It won't double the size, but it will increase it. I'll add an example in my answer for without copy_to.

Comment: I've added an example of your query should look like in order for it to work with nested and simple fields.

Comment: Is there a way to add the nested query without specify the specific fields inside it? Just search in the whole fields in the nested field (which his name will be hard coded)?

Comment: The query for the nested fields as well as the other one, are multi_match queries. The fields section can be the wildcard `*` which means all fields. You can do this `"fields": ["*"]` as well as this `"fields": ["user.*"]` if you want more control

Comment: So can I just use the wildcard "*" without change the code I used until now? Why do I have to modify the query specific for nested fields? I still didn't understand what to change in the code I published in order to match for fields inside a nested field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212644/discussion-between-alkis-kalogeris-and-roy-leibovitz).